# How to place a image inside a square of canvas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, canvas

Well, I have a canvas element on my page where will be a Snake Game. I'm trying to place one image inside the square of the canvas with the `context.drawImage()`.

Bellow you can see what I want:

[[image: Concept]

My load image code on the context is that:

```js
function SnakeTexture(context, x, y) {
  const Texture = new Image();
  Texture.src = '../../assets/images/snake.png';
  Texture.onload = () => {
    context.drawImage(Texture, x, x, 16, 16);
  }
}

export { SnakeTexture };
```

On the main file they appears here:

```js
/* GAME CONTEXTS */
const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
context.setTransform(16, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0);
context.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 320);

/* SNAKE STYLE */
SnakeTexture(context, snake[0], snake[1])
```

#### I have tried:

- Put the Texture.src after the load.
- Use a URL as image src.
- Change the size of Texture.

Answer (score 0):

I did it! I'm using Node.js, so I install a dependency call canvas, were have a loadImage function, so, what i did is just:

```js
loadImage(SnakeTexture).then(img => {
   snake.forEach(([x, y]) => context.drawImage(img, x, y, 1, 1));
})
```